# SQL truncate length of a string

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have a table programmers (id, name) in postgreSQL and i want to return names of all programmers and if a name has more than 12 characters i want to truncate it to exactly 12 characters, any ideas how can i do that?

Comment: `Select LEFT(name,12)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

```
select substring(name from 1 for 12) from your_table
```

Referred https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html

Or the comment mentioned by @Prdp is a better alternative I think. Check the cost for both and use the one suits you.

Comment: Check `LEFT(name,12)` as mentioned by @Prdp also. Compare the cost and use which works better for you.
If the answer works for you, then accept it so the question could be closed. Cheers.